# Tap into display signal

Tags: display

(Newbie Arduino developer).

I am interested to read the signal being sent to a small flat screen display in an industrial appliance, while not disturbing the display. The goal is to capture screenshots and upload them over a network connection.

Is that possible. What do I need to find out about the signal/display?

Any pointers to get started, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ¿What do you mean? Simply read a HIGH/LOW voltage, a current, or you want to be read what char/text/value is displayed? I'm also interested in reading what is displayed in old cell phone (the ones wth physical buttons).

Comment: Depends on how much resources (time and money) you have. An AVR based Arduino will have a hardtime capturing display signals and holding and uploading the image. The simples solution is a web-cam.

Comment: If you want to interface electronically: Different display technologies (LED and LCD being the most likely of many) combined with many different electronic protocols makes this question too vague to even start to answer. If you want to build an optical interface: To understand patterns captured by a camera, often people use computer vision.  OpenCV is a commonly used software package for computer vision.  However, OpenCV requires a very robust computer to run on.  So only the high end Arduino boards with real operating systems are viable options for this purpose.

Comment: On the other hand, if it's a little text-only LCD, being driven not too fast, you might stand a chance as the protocol is fairly simple. More information required certainly.

Comment: Will try to see what information can be gathered, when I have it taken apart the next time.